# apply searchsorted columnwise

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to implement forward sampling in python using the numpy library. I have some variables that hold the conditional probability tables and I would like to draw a random sample from these tables. For the roots in the bayesian network, this code is simply:

```
ls = L.cumsum().searchsorted(random.sample(n))
```

where `L` is the (C)PT as a (one-dimensional) numpy array and `n` is the number of samples I want to take.

Now I want to do the same thing for a real conditional probability table. Unfortunately the previous code is not applicable anymore, because I now have to take the chosen `l` into account which results in some table with two dimensions and thus `searchsorted()` cannot handle it. (e.g. `P_L[:,ls].cumsum(0)` gives an array that looks like `[[.8 .8 ... ] [1. 1. ...]]`

I've found a way to work around to make this work:

```
randomness = random.sample(n)
ps = ndarray(ls.shape, int)
for i in 0,1 :
    mask = ls == i
    ps[mask] = P_L[:,i].cumsum().searchsorted(randomness[mask])
```

but I think this is a rather dirty way to do this and I wanted to know if anyone would know how I could write this in a more decent/clean way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately applying `np.searchsorted` along a specific axis currently isn't possible without a Python loop. [There's been some discussion about adding an `axis` keyword argument to `np.searchsorted`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4224), but it looks like it would be complicated to implement.

Comment: Does this mean there is no clean (maybe common) alternative to my code?

Comment: Is your concern about performance or cleanliness?

Comment: @ali_m Performance is not an issue (yet), but I might be interested in both aspects...